# how can i remove array from STDObject?

Tags: php, arrays, object, joomla, stdclass

**Hello!!**

i think its very simple question for those who familier with std objects and arrays in PHP.

**Here is my STD Object array:**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name1 [description] => [category_id] => 17 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 1 [category_parent_id] => 10 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name2 [description] => [category_id] => 8 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 1 [category_parent_id] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name3 [description] =>desc [category_id] => 10 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 2 [category_parent_id] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name3 [description] => [category_id] => 16 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 2 [category_parent_id] => 10 ) )
```

now, i have different array with numbers for example:

```
$arr=array(17,10);
```

and i need to check if one of this numbers is equal the [category_id] value (inside the std object), if it is equal, check the next [category_id], and if it's not, remove all values of this object .
(of course, Other method is to build a new STD Object only with the numbers in the array)

**So the result should be:**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name1 [description] => [category_id] => 17 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 1 [category_parent_id] => 10 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name3 [description] =>desc [category_id] => 10 [category_publish] => 1 [ordering] => 2 [category_parent_id] => 0 ) )
```

Only the array's with categiry_id =17 and 10 are inside this stdObject..

Thank you very much for your help!!

Eran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr=array(17,10);
foreach ($array as $key => $obj) {
  if (!in_array($obj->category_id, $arr)) {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
} 
// edited, missing closing bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to filter what you want or what you don't want

```
$filterCategory = array(17,10);
$array = array_filter($yourArray,function($var) use($filterCategory) { return in_array($var->category_id, $filterCategory); } );
```